# Android Button onClick listener error?

Tags: android

i Have the following code:

in onCreate method:

```
{
saveClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
        saveClick.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        //------------ take input data and save in DB --------------------
        String cpassword;
        EditText num_1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1);
        EditText num_2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passkey1);
        EditText num_3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passkey2);
        number=num_1.getText().toString();
        password=num_2.getText().toString();
        cpassword=num_3.getText().toString();

        DBoperation db=DBoperation.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        if(password == cpassword)
        {
            TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            pnumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
            db.addSIMSs(pnumber);
            db.addSIMSs(number);
            db.addPassKey(password);
        }
    }
```

i am using eclipse for development and it keeps giving the following errors:
**at line:saveClick.setOnClickListener(this);

error:

the method setOnClickListener(View.setOnClickListener) in the type view is not applicable for the arguments.**

**also at line:public void onClick(View v) {

error:

the method onClick(View) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method.**

following is the XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="113dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/num1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passkey1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/num1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/num1"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passkey2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passkey1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passkey1"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pass1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/passkey1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pass2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/passkey2"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pass1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passkey2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:text="@string/save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you implemented OnClicklistener to your Activity?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line.-

```
saveClick.setOnClickListener(this);
```

I'm guessing `this` is an instance of `Activity`, when it should be an `OnClickListener`. Try something like this instead.-

```
saveClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Do your stuff here    
    }
});
```

As for the second error, the compiler is complaining that you're trying to override method `onClick` in your `Activity`, but its parent doesn't implement that method. Just remove `onClick` method from the `Activity`, and move that logic to the listener `onClick` method.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement the `OnCLickListener` in your class initializing. That is 
`public class MyClass extends Activity implements View.OnCLickListener`

Answer (score 0):

Use this , it will work.

```
saveClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
saveClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String cpassword;
        EditText num_1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1);
        EditText num_2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passkey1);
        EditText num_3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passkey2);
        number=num_1.getText().toString();
        password=num_2.getText().toString();
        cpassword=num_3.getText().toString();

        DBoperation db=DBoperation.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        if(password == cpassword)
        {
            TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            pnumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
            db.addSIMSs(pnumber);
            db.addSIMSs(number);
            db.addPassKey(password);
        }
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have problem in importing library of onclicklistner; which seems you have done

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

why dont you try with

```
saveClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Do your stuff here    
    }
});
```

rather then

```
saveClick.setOnClickListener(this);
```

which will help you to debug futher

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your onClick

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.saveBtn) {

    //your code
        String cpassword;
                EditText num_1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1);
                EditText num_2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passkey1);
                EditText num_3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passkey2);
                number=num_1.getText().toString();
                password=num_2.getText().toString();
                cpassword=num_3.getText().toString();

                DBoperation db=DBoperation.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                if(password == cpassword)
                {
                    TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    pnumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
                    db.addSIMSs(pnumber);
                    db.addSIMSs(number);
                    db.addPassKey(password);
                }

}
```